# Как закрыть 2 всплывающих окна при клике на div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-form

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть форма которая отправляет данные на почту, после успешной отправки всплывает окно с уведомлением `"Сообщение отправлено - ОК"`, чтобы закрыть все окна нужно сначала закрыть окно с уведомлением об успешной отправке, а потом еще саму форму. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы при клике на всплывающее окно в котором выводится уведомление об успешной отправке закрывалось всплывающее окно с самой формой?
Сайт http://jrjakcomber.com/

Comment: еще в поисках ответа

Comment: Советую почитать  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help